# How do I create a Map Icon?

Tags: iphone, gps

My app currently texts the user's GPS coordinates, after which the receipent enters them into the MAP app that comes with our iPhones. I just discovered that it is somehow possible to create an icon that the receipent merely clicks on to bring up the MAP app, where it displays a map showing the location of the coordinates, along with the exact address. I was so impressed with the accuracy and ease of use that I want to modify my app to text an icon, instead of the GPS coordinates. I spend all day researching but can't find how to do it. (Maybe I haven't looked in the right places, so please excuse me if I'm wasting time.)

The icon I'm trying to create (and text) is the one that you would create if you were looking at a location using the MAP app. After you tap the disclosure button it displays detailed info. At the bottom of the screen is a button entitled, "Share Location." If you click it, you then have the option of clicking another button entitled, "Message." a text message gets generated with an icon that represents a pin with a red head. This is what I'd like to create.
If it's possible, can somebody point me to where I can find more information, hopefully, including sample code?

Answer (score 0):

Not all users have the ability to text images.  The best option might be to just use the text...  Also when you ask how to create the icon, what do you mean?  The actual image?

Comment: Thanks. I just found out this can't be done. The "icon" I was referring to was created via MMS message in an Apple developed app. I was able to do something just as good by creating a Map Link URL and texting it.